# my AVD emulator in Android Studio keeps crashing

Tags: android

I can't change the graphics to software in order to fix my AVD not launching. The option is greyed out. Has anyone experience this? I couldn't find anyone who had the same issue.

I'm running the latest version of Android Studio on chipmunk.

Answer (score 0):

> try deleting the emulator first then make a new one also delete it on Drive C:android/AVD and try running it again